# Does sqlalchemy need synchronization primitives in asynchronous usage?

Tags: asynchronous, sqlalchemy, io, python-asyncio

i want to use sqlalchemy in my bot which asyncio. I am aware that there is a asynchronous implementation of sqlalchemy (https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/extensions/asyncio.html#preventing-implicit-io-when-using-asyncsession). But I couldn't get any information regarding how it handles IO collisions i.e. a SQL request is made when another request is going on (so something like func 1 awaits get statement and event loop jumps to func 2 which awaits a set statement while the initial statement is not finished executing). Would I need to use asyncio primitives like locks to ensure my code doesn't error out on such instances?